# Method to split string and add to different rows in excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, split

I have a method that creates an excel sheet from a list of strings. The strings are details that are like:

> Name: Obi Wan Kenobi

> Location: Tattooine

So far, when creating an excel sheet in c#, I'm able to add it to all to individual rows. However, I would like to split each string at the colon and add them to separate columns. I want it to look something like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Name | Obi Wan Kenobi |
| Location | Tattooine |

So far I've tried this:

```
public static void CreateExcelSheet(List<string> list)
{
    var wb = new XLWorkbook();
    var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Data_Test_Worksheet");

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            var detail = item.Split(':');
            ws.Cell(i + 1, 1).InsertData(detail[0]);
            ws.Cell(i + 1, 2).InsertData(detail[1]);
        }              
    }

    wb.SaveAs(@"c:\temp\Data_Text.xlsx");
}
```

This is how I though the logic would play out but when I execute it, it errors.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: I would use left() and right() based on finding the colon.

Comment: You should only need one for loop. You are looping through the 2 items here twice. I would have thought you would get "Location Tattooine" twice by reading the code rather than an error

Comment: *"when I execute it, it errors."* It would be helpful if you posted the error message.

Comment: @KristianFitzgerald Ok I've removed the foreach and left the for loop. It now saves fine but the excel sheet is turning out blank.

Comment: From example code online, it looks like InsertData is for adding a list of data rather than one value. ws.Cell(i + 1, 1).Value = detail[0]; should work. Or the Answer posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is the methods you are using, its kinda not finding the right place to write your data.

Try adding the `var row = ws.Row(i + 1);` to get the current row and then just set the values like this `row.Cell(1).Value = detail[0];`

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateExcelSheet(new List<string> {
                "s:1",
                "s:2"
            });
        }

        public static void CreateExcelSheet(List<string> list)
        {
            var wb = new XLWorkbook();
            var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Data_Test_Worksheet");

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                var detail = list[i].Split(':');
                var row = ws.Row(i + 1);
                row.Cell(1).Value = detail[0];
                row.Cell(2).Value = detail[1];
            }

            wb.SaveAs(@"Data_Text.xlsx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing. Thank you!